# estimation of correlation coefficient of reduced data

Tags: estimation

Suppose (X,Y) $\sim$  Bivariate Normal Distribution. We know only the signs of X's and Y's. How can we estimate the correlation coefficient $\rho$  using this reduced data?

Comment: To succeed, you need different data or to adopt strong assumptions (such as a Bayes prior). The reason is that there is not enough information to estimate $\rho$; it is consistent with a two-parameter family of bivariate Normal distributions and (for most datasets) $\rho$ varies throughout that family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way I'd probably think about this is that the X's and Y's have been reduced to nominal dichotomous variables. In this case a correlation estimate could be obtained from the point biserial correlation coefficient or Cramer's phi (I'd probably go with Cramer's phi):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V

I'd need to do some more work to understand the bias related to the true value of the Pearson Product Moment Correlation Coefficient in the non-dichotomized values, but an off hand initial thought would be that it would exaggerate weak positive or negative correlations because you only have sign, and not magnitude.

Comment: Why should these *different* correlation coefficients reflect the parameter $\rho$ of a binormal distribution in anything but a qualitative sense?